# What is the best way to validate monthly subscription in react native?

Tags: react-native, in-app-subscription

My react app uses `react-native-iap` module for in app purchases and It has a monthly subscription. I am facing few problems with validating my monthly subscription and I couldn't find any solution for that.

When user do a subscription first it will validate and update the `state` of my app as `subscribed`.

If user close the app and open it again also the validation will happen and update the state of the app as subscribed.

But user does not close the app, then there is no method to validate the subscription. User can use premium features until he/she close the app.

I tried with `setInterval` and periodically send request to the server to validate , but this method will reduce the performance of my android app drastically. So I can not use that method also.

Is there a correct/best way to validate monthly subscription periodically ? or Did I miss something by implementing monthly subscription ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are users purchasing the monthly subscription in app? Is it possible to add a callback to the `purchaseUpdatedListener()` to update the subscription state upon successful purchase?

Comment: yes it is possible.